# Docker Volume mapping Error on Mac with Windows Container

Tags: sql-server, macos, docker, containers, docker-compose

I am currently running https://github.com/StefanScherer/docker-windows-box, basically a VirtualBox hosted windows docker-machine.

Everything seems to work fine but I cannot seem to figure out how to map the volumes from Mac to the windows container?  Specifically I am trying out microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer with

```
volumes:
   - ./data/:c:/data
```

in the docker-compose.yml file, but it is throwing invalid volume spec "c": invalid volume specification: 'c'

Anyone got any idea how I can map the volumes from Mac to Windows?

Comment: Have you tried removing `c:` from `- ./data/:c:/data`

Comment: like ./data/:/data? yes

Comment: Yes! Because the configuration you are providing does not seem valid. You may also try using [long syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-3)

Comment: yeah tried those...same error, problem is with the C:\ in windows container